# WP_Query with meta_value_num and meta_query not paged correctly

Tags: wp-query, pagination, meta-query

I have a strange thing with my WP_Query, where isn't paged correctly.

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $limit, // 10
    'paged' => $page, // paged param
    'order' => $order, // ASC
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'ma_rate_percents',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'ma_rating_up',
            'compare' => '>',
            'value' => 0,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'ma_rating_down',
            'compare' => '>',
            'value' => 0,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

In my example i get 412 results in $posts->found_posts and on first page i see 10 post id's. If i go to page=2 i get already 10 post id's, but with the last 2 ID's by page 1, on page 3 i get 4 ID's of page 2 and so on.

What's wrong with this Query? I'm also resetted the query with wp_reset_query() on the end, but nothing helps. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Can you show the logic for the limit and page variables?

Comment: for sure, `$limit = !empty($_GET['limit']) ? intval($_GET['limit']) : 10;` and `$page = !empty($_GET['site']) ? intval($_GET['site']) : 1;`. This $_GET fires into on WP backend on a plugin page.

Comment: Your posts_per_page GET variable must be changing on different pages. What happens if you hardcode that value to 10 instead of using a variable?

Comment: Nope, the same happends, if i put static posts_per_page = 10 into the query.

Comment: I'd recommend not using `$posts`, as this should be reserved for the main query - use something like `$my_posts` instead.  But anyway, after the query try `var_dump($my_posts);` and look at the parameters in `$my_posts->query`. Also eusure that the limit and offset in the query are actually as you would expect in `$my_posts->request`;. If you are unsure on how to interpret the query, update your question to include it and we'll help.

Comment: for sure, i have check all the output again and again, the limit and offset into the SQL Query are correct, but i'm not sure with the inner joins into the query (2 times into the query).